# C - using realloc on pointer to pointer result in segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, memory, realloc

I am trying to use realloc since i want to improve speed in my code. When a certain condition is fulfilled, I want to realloc a void double pointer to a larger size, but I get a segmentation fault. Here is the code.

```
if (p_bheap->currentSize == p_bheap->arraySize){
    p_bheap->arraySize = p_bheap->arraySize*2 + 1;
    p_bheap->pp_array = realloc(p_bheap->pp_array, p_bheap->arraySize);
}
```

This however results in a segmentation fault. If I however make my own reallocating function it works.

```
if (p_bheap->currentSize == p_bheap->arraySize){
    p_bheap->pp_array = bheap_reallocate(p_bheap);
}

void** bheap_reallocate(bheap* p_bheap){
    p_bheap->arraySize = p_bheap->arraySize*2 + 1;
    void** pp_newArray = malloc(p_bheap->arraySize*sizeof(void*));
    for (int i = 0; i < p_bheap->currentSize; i++){
        pp_newArray[i] = p_bheap->pp_array[i];
    }
    free(p_bheap->pp_array);
    return pp_newArray;
}
```

Is there any clear errors that can be spotted that I have failed to see? And for those wondering I am programming a binary heap.

Comment: The size passed to [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is just like the size passed to [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc): The size in ***bytes*** (not elements).

Comment: By the way, never assign the result of [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) back to the pointer you passed as argument. If [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) fails it will return `NULL` and you will lose the original pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: I didn't quite catch your solution. What is it that I must alter?

Comment: You do the right thing when calling `malloc` regarding the size. Now think about how the size in `realloc` should be calculated...

Comment: Oh jesus thanks. I forgot the multiplication.

Comment: And, BTW, the style `p = malloc(count * sizeof *p);` will avoid this kind of problem (similar for realloc)

Comment: Some programmer dude, wouldn't it make sense if I kept it as it is, and instead exit the program in case of a NULL pointer? If the system is out of memory it seems a little unnecessary to be afraid of losing the memory?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: There are cases where it might be useful to continue even when low on memory. It has to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a previously allocated object, say `str` and want to adjust its memory to another size, use a temporary variable to prevent memory loss in the event `realloc` fails.  Illustration:

```
char *str = calloc(20, 1);
if(str) // should always check return of calls to [c][m][re]alloc.
{ // at this point, str owns 20 bytes of memory.  If you use str in a subsequent
  // call to realloc, and the call fails, then the memory previously allocated in 
  // the original call to calloc() will be lost.  (memory leak).
....
char *tmp = {0};//So instead, use a temporary variable to accept memory
                //and provide a way to recover if allocation fails

tmp = realloc(str, 40);//newsize (40) in bytes
if(!tmp) //test reallocation
{
    //reallocation failed.
    //free previously allocated memory, and decide how to proceed.
    //In this case, return a NULL, and let the calling function decide.
    free(str);//if allocation fails, free the previous object and leave
    return NULL;
}
//reallocation succeeded.  Proceed normally
str = tmp;//reallocation succeeded, assign its address to str and proceed normally
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the same memory space to receive the result. Try to use a temporary array or to allocate another space.

Comment: This is *a* problem, but it's not *the* problem the OP have.